# How to set timeout request for EJB transfer?

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I have an EJB called `ServiceImplRemote`. This EJB is requested from my final service class by the following method:

```
...

ServiceImplRemote serviceImplRemote = 
beanFactory.getBean("ServiceImplEJB",ServiceImplRemote.class);
Collection<UserDTO> result = 
serviceImplRemote.userRequired({function param}, {function param});
return result;

...
```

How I set timeout for `userRequired` function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @AccessTimeout

```
@AccessTimeout(0)
public void doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```

[Useful link](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/access-timeout/)